# Continuous partial derivative in one parameter and $L^1$ continuity with respect to another parameter implies continuity

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus

I want to solve the following question.

> Let $f\left(x,y\right)$ be a bounded function whose first partial derivative with respect to $x$ is continuous. Suppose that
> $$
> \lim_{h\rightarrow0}\,\int_{-1}^{1}\left|f\left(x,y+h\right)-f\left(x,y\right)\right|\mathrm{d}x=0
> $$
> for every $y\in\left(-1,1\right)$. Prove that $f\left(x,y\right)$
> is continuous on $\left(-1,1\right)\times\left(-1,1\right)$.

For any $(x_{0},y_{0})\in (-1,1)\times (-1,1)$, we hope to estimate
$$
|f\left(x,y\right)-f\left(x_{0},y_{0}\right)|\leq |f\left(x,y\right)-f\left(x_{0},y\right)|+|f\left(x_{0},y\right)-f\left(x_{0},y_{0}\right)|
$$
By the continuity of $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\left(x,y\right)$, the first term is small whenever $(x,y)$ is closed to $(x_{0},y_{0})$. However, I have no idea to estimate the second term or use the $L^{1}$ continuity assumption.

Thanks in advance.